# How to Compare one value with all list entries in one step?

Tags: java, algorithm

For a special slope for linear distances, I need to check wether a new point with given lat/lon has a distance greater than 10 km with respect to all other points, which are stored in a map. I'd like to avoid, that all points inside the map are compared sequentially.

I tried the following code:

```
private static Map<Long,String> getTop10DSEGs() throws IOException  {
    Map<Long,String> top10Dsegs = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> allDsegs = loadDsegRanking(rFiles);
    //the list allDsegs is a csv with the following structure
    //dsegID, Latitide, Longitude
    //1167317891449551556,51.435550689697266,6.695819854736328
    double LatFromList, LonFromList;
    double LatFromMap, LonFromMap;
    String[] listArray;
    String[] mapArray;
    Long firstDseg = Long.parseLong(allDsegs.get(0).substring(0, 19));
    top10Dsegs.put(firstDseg, allDsegs.get(0).substring(20));
    //Iterating through all dsegs
    for(String line : allDsegs){
        Long nextID = null; 
        String nextCoordinates = "0.0000,0.0000";
        listArray = line.split(",");
        LatFromList = Double.valueOf(listArray[1]);
        LonFromList = Double.valueOf(listArray[2]);
        //checking all coordinates of maped dsegs
        for(Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : top10Dsegs.entrySet()){
            List<Double> distanceList = new ArrayList<>();
            mapArray = entry.getValue().split(",");
            LatFromMap = Double.valueOf(mapArray[0]);
            LonFromMap = Double.valueOf(mapArray[1]);
            //calculating the distance between the next city from the list and the other dsegs from the map
            //result of dist is a double and it's metric is Km.
            Double dist = Implements.DistanceCalculator.distance(LatFromMap, LonFromMap, LatFromList, LonFromList, "K");
            distanceList.add(dist);
            for(Double value : distanceList){
                if (dist>10){
                    nextID = Long.parseLong(listArray[0]);
                    nextCoordinates = listArray[1] + "," + listArray[2];
                }
            }
        }
        if(nextID != null && top10Dsegs.size() < 10){
            top10Dsegs.put(nextID, nextStartCoordinates);
        }
return top10Dsegs;      
}
```

Comment: really a nice algorithm it is

Comment: (1) What does "in one step" mean? (2) You need to check a list of points or *"a new point"*? If it's a list, is it sorted somehow? (3) Which map is the one that stores the points and what do the keys and values represent? (4) Why do you want to avoid that *"that all points inside the map are compared sequentially"*? (4) How often does that map change? (5) Can you use streams?

Comment: Sorting the initial list would greatly help in eliminating points faster...

Comment: the alogorithm is now edited.
(2)A new geocoordinate from _allDsegs_ (sorted by a attribute, which isn't given) will be compared with a given number of other coordinates, which are stored (3) in a map<Long[geoID],String[Lat,Lon]> top10Dsegs.

Comment: (4) I need to avoid the sequential algorithm, because of this example:
(distance between cities should be more than 400 km)
4.1 city in the map is Los Angeles
4.2 Los Angeles need to be compared to New York City
4.3. distance(LA,NYC) = 4000 km
4.4 New York City will be added to the map
4.5 new city is Washington
4.6 Washington need to be compared with LA and NYC
4.7 if Washington is ONLY compared to LA, Washington will be added to the map. But the distance between Washington and NYC wasn't checked.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid calculating and comparing distance between all the already stored points and the new one you may use some kind of grid (or matrix) implemented by (Multi)Map or array. Each cell of the grid may have size of sqrt(10km) and contains all the points with relevant coords. It is easy to calculate coordinates of suitable cell for the point by dividing it's coords by sqrt(10).

So when adding every next point it is possible to check distance to only points in 9 cells (own + around). I suppose it will be much less than all points on the map.

Comment: Did you misunderstand my problem?
I need to compare new values with all stored points. There is a predefined list and another list (which is a map). The another list should only store dsegs which distances are greater than 10 km at all.

Comment: If you don't want to use any other strictures to store the points or modify input list, I think, there is no other way than comparing all the distances.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [anyMatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) in the Java 8 Stream API

```
boolean exists = allDsegs.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.equals(firstDseg /* or whetever you compare */));
```

Comment: Just because you don't see the iteration in your program does not mean it does not happen.

Comment: OK, but how can you compare a value with values in a list without go through the list? I understand the question that he does  not want to implement the iteration

Comment: One could use another data structure that allows to find nearby points faster than iterating through all.

Comment: Of course you can do that -- which would be a totally different question

Comment: @Henry:
Is there another way to compare linear distances between geopoints? While a new point is added, the algorithm then should compare the linear distances of further geopoints with respect to the given two points. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Henry:
I use to add that I don't need to find nearby points. It's the opposite. I need to find points, which are far away from each other.

Comment: @PaulGustav isn't that the same? If there is no nearby point, it is far away from all others.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys.

Now I solved it by using the Stream-Api and there allMatch()-Method. The problem was, that I've created a Map to save new elements and furthermore the test `check = allDsegs.stream().anyMatch(x->dist>10);` was the wrong. 
The solution is to use a list(top10List) for the new elements and the test need to check if there are elements in the top10List, which are smaller than 10 km.

Here is the code, which (unfortunately) is not beautiful. Im just a beginner since 7 months:

```
private static List<Top10Dsegs> getTop10DSEGs() throws IOException  {
    List<File>rFiles = getRFiles();
    List<String> allDsegs = loadDsegRanking(rFiles);
    List<Top10Dsegs> top10List = new ArrayList<>();
    double startLat_allDsegs, startLon_allDsegs;
    double startLat_top10List, startLon_top10List;
    String[] listArray;
    //declaring the starting dseg and its coordinates
    String startEntry = allDsegs.get(0);
    Top10Dsegs firstEntry = new Top10Dsegs(startEntry);
    top10List.add(firstEntry);
    System.out.println("Iteration starts here!\n---------------------");
    //begin to iterate over all entries (just ranked)
        for(String line : allDsegs){
            boolean check=true;
            Top10Dsegs nextEntry=null;
            //structure from allDsegs:
            //DSEG,startLat,startLon
            //1231231231231231231, 54.123, 8.456
            listArray = line.split(",");
            startLat_allDsegs = Double.valueOf(listArray[1]);
            startLon_allDsegs = Double.valueOf(listArray[2]);

            //start to check if line-entry of allDsegs has a distance > 10 km compared to given Dsegs
            for(Top10Dsegs entry : top10List){
                startLat_top10List = entry.getStartLat();
                startLon_top10List = entry.getStartLon();
                //the DistanceCalculator calculates the distance between the dseg from allDsegs and the other dseg from top10Dsegs
                DistanceCalculator distanceCalculator = new DistanceCalculator();
                Double dist = distanceCalculator.distance(startLat_top10List, startLon_top10List, startLat_allDsegs, startLon_allDsegs, "K");
                System.out.println("Checked Dseg: " + listArray[0]);
                System.out.println("Distance between checked Dseg and " + entry.getSegmentID() + " = " + dist);
                //check if there is a dseg from allDsegs distance > 10 km compared to ALL OTHER dsegs
                if(top10List.stream().allMatch(x->dist<10)==true){
                check = false;
                }
                System.out.println("Are all distances > 10 ? \t" + check);  
            }
            if(check==true && top10List.size()<10){
                nextEntry = new Top10Dsegs(listArray[0]+","+listArray[1]+","+listArray[2]);
                top10List.add(nextEntry);
            }
            System.out.println("Progress: \n"+top10List.size()+" entries inside top 10 list. \n<---------------->\nNext Iteration:");
    }
    return top10List;
}
```